# vscode dev container environment variables not exposing to docker-compose

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services: 
  vscode:
    volumes:
      - ..:/workspace:cached
      - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment: 
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent
```

Problem is that vscode does not want to give any kind of possibility to do an equivalent of `docker-compose run --env ...` thus I'm left with

```
WARNING: The SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

Is there any way for me to expose my variables from my host to the dev container without using an `.env` file or anything like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have opened an issue on github yesterday. The outcome is that **if you use WSL**, then you need to export this variable through your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile.

> We are using a non-interactive login shell to probe the environment variables in WSL and use these as the "local" variables.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5806

Answer (score -2):

I just had a similar issue so this may help.

I would run the following:

```
export VARIABLE=VALUE
sudo docker-compose up
```

The problem was that I was exporting the environment variable as my user and then running docker-compose as sudo so it wouldn't have the same environment variables.

This can be solved by either adding yourself to the docker group so you can run without sudo

or exporting the variable as root(not recommended)

Comment: This question is specific to VS code dev containers. Not specific to docker-compose. It seems like eventually this was fixed, see: The fool's answer